# Looping Through Array Until Solution Found

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have the array below with the first value of each array being the road name, the second value being any connections to the road and third can be ignore for now (all fake roads). I am currently trying to find the quickest route (least steps) from one road to another by looking at the connections.. My code is currently looking through phases defined by myself, but as I add further connections I'll have to add further logic - is there anyway of looping through an undefined amount until it finds best route (there will be no point where it can't find a route)?

**Array:**

```
  var road = [
        //Name, connection, [left, middle, right]
            ["Upper-G", ["Lower-G", "Left Corner", "Top Corner"], []],
            ["Upper-TW", ["Lower-TW", "Left Corner", "Right Corner"], []],
            ["Upper-RG", ["Lower-RG", "Upper-RG", "Top Corner", "Right Corner"], []],
            ["Lower-G", ["Upper-G", "Left Corner", "Top Corner"], [] ],
            ["Lower-TW", ["Upper-TW", "Lower-PD", "Upper-PD", "Left Corner", "Right Corner"], []],
            ["Lower-RG", ["Upper-RG", "Top Corner", "Right Corner"], []],
            ["Left Corner", ["Lower-G", "Upper-G", "Lower-TW", "Upper-TW"], []],
            ["Top Corner", ["Upper-G", "Lower-G", "Lower-RG", "Upper-RG"], []],
            ["Right Corner", ["Upper-RG", "Lower-RG", "Upper-TW", "Lower-TW"], []],
            ["Upper-PD", ["Lower-PD", "Lower-TW", "Upper-TW"], []],
            ["Lower-PD", ["Upper-PD", "Lower-TW", "Upper-TW"], []]
        ];
```

**Code:**
I call findPath('roadWeAreAt', 'roadToGetTo') to get a result

```
function findPath(cRoad, fRoad){
        //Find roads in array
        var cOriginalPos = findRoadInArr(cRoad);
        var fOriginalPos = findRoadInArr(fRoad);

        //If either cannot be found, return undefined
        if(cOriginalPos == undefined || fOriginalPos == undefined){
            return "undefined";
        }

        //Target arrays for ease and add first road to directions
        var cRoadArray = road[cOriginalPos];
        var fRoadArray = road[fOriginalPos];
        var roadDirections = findBestPath(cRoadArray, fRoadArray);

        //found or not
        if(roadDirections != undefined){
            console.log(roadDirections);
        }
        else {

            console.log("not found");
        }

    }

    function findBestPath(cRoadArray, fRoadArray){
        var roadDirections = findInitialPath(cRoadArray, fRoadArray);

        if(roadDirections == undefined){
            roadDirections = findSecondPath(cRoadArray, fRoadArray);

            if(roadDirections == undefined){
                roadDirections = findThirdPath(cRoadArray, fRoadArray);

                if(roadDirections == undefined){
                    roadDirections = findFourthPath(cRoadArray, fRoadArray);
                }
            }
        }
        return roadDirections;
    }

    function findInitialPath(cRoadArray, fRoadArray){
    var roadDirections = [cRoadArray[0]];
        //Loop through current roadarray
        for(var i = 0; i < cRoadArray[1].length; i++){
            //If it's next to each other
            if(cRoadArray[1][i] == fRoadArray[0]){
                roadDirections.push(fRoadArray[0]);
                return roadDirections;
            }
        }
    }


    function findSecondPath(cRoadArray, fRoadArray){
        var roadDirections = [cRoadArray[0]];
        //Loop through current roadarray
        for(var i = 0; i < cRoadArray[1].length; i++){
            //If its in an inbetween road
            for(var j = 0; j < fRoadArray[1].length; j++){
                if(cRoadArray[1][i] == fRoadArray[1][j]){
                    roadDirections.push(cRoadArray[1][i]);
                    roadDirections.push(fRoadArray[0]);
                    return roadDirections;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function findThirdPath(cRoadArray, fRoadArray){
        var roadDirections = [cRoadArray[0]];

        //Loop through current roadArray
        for(var i = 0; i < cRoadArray[1].length; i++){
            var newcurrentroad = road[findRoadInArr(cRoadArray[1][i])];
            //Loop through 
            var tryDirections = findSecondPath(newcurrentroad, fRoadArray);

            if(tryDirections != undefined){
                //roadDirections.push(cRoadArray[1][i]);
                for(var j = 0; j < tryDirections.length; j++){
                    roadDirections.push(tryDirections[j]);
                }
                return roadDirections;
            }
        }
    }

    function findFourthPath(cRoadArray, fRoadArray){
        var roadDirections = [cRoadArray[0]];

        for(var i = 0; i < cRoadArray[1].length; i++){
            var newcurrentroad = road[findRoadInArr(cRoadArray[1][i])];
            //Loop through 
            var tryDirections = findThirdPath(newcurrentroad, fRoadArray);

            if(tryDirections != undefined){
                for(var j = 0; j < tryDirections.length; j++){
                    roadDirections.push(tryDirections[j]);
                }
                return roadDirections;
            }
        }   
    }


    function findRoadInArr(roadName){
        for(var i = 0; i < road.length; i++){
            if(road[i][0] == roadName){
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: have a look at Dijkstra algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: This is known as the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) and is of a class of problems known as [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness). The _best_ (shortest) path can only be guaranteed to be found by enumerating _every_ possible path.  As far as looping goes, you'll just go from `0` to `road.length - 1` for an "undefined" amount. Or learn about Dijkstra's as melli mentions.

Comment: Could you provide any help in doing that continuous loop for my situation..  I'm not sure how to achieve the logic in trying every combination..

Comment: @StephenP, this is actually not the Traveling Salesman Problem. The OP does not need to go through all nodes, it only needs to find the shortest path from A to B, so SPF (Dijkstra's) is the right solution.

Comment: @jcaron - you're right, my initial reading jumped from looping through all array entries to mean visit all nodes, overlooking the statement _"from one road to another"_

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their help, once I could find what the algorthims are I came across this neat solution which will do exactly what I need:
https://github.com/qiao/PathFinding.js/